# can't display data from database on template

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm a beginner in django and my problem is : 
I already have data in my database, but I can't display it on my template.

I tried multiples times to change my view's function and the template language but nothing works for me

in views.py

```
def my_financial_data(request):
    mydata = DataItem.objects.all()
    print(mydata)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'mydata': mydata})
```

in models.py

```
class DataItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    lastprice = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    sinceclose = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    sinceopen = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    isin = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

in my template

```
<div>
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="bg-dark">
            <tr>
              <th class="text-light">Name</th>
              <th class="text-light">Last Price</th>
              <th class="text-light">Change since Close</th>
              <th class="text-light">Change since Open</th>
              <th class="text-light">Isin</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

            <tbody>

            {% for item in mydata %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-primary"> {{item.name}} </td>
                    <td class="text-dark"> {{ item.lastprice }} </td>
                    <td class="text-dark"> {{ item.sinceclose }} </td>
                    <td class="text-dark"> {{ item.sinceopen }} </td>
                    <td class="text-dark"> {{ item.isin }} </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', lambda request: redirect('accounts/login/', permanent=False)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    #path('blog/', financial_data_render),
    path('blog/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), # If the login is right, it's redirecting to home.html
    path('blog', views.DataItem),
    path('blog/add-isin/', views.add_row),
    path('blog/add-place/', views.add_row),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) # for the static files
```

What I want is, when I open my site, the data saved is displayed.

Thank you very much for your help ^^

Comment: Hello! What is the output of your `print` statement?

Comment: What happens when you open your site? Does the template get rendered at all?

Comment: Hello Al Amin, I can't see my print. I might be stupid but I don't know where i can check this print

Comment: Hello Higor, when i open my site nothing get rendered  ...

Comment: How does your urls look like?

Comment: i edited the post, u can check the url

Answer (score 0):

Url don't be same. But yours blog/ and blog.

> ```
> path('blog/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'), # If the login is right, it's redirecting to home.html
> path('blog', views.DataItem),
> ```

Comment: you mean that I have to create another view to display my data right ?

Comment: You defined two view for one path. This isn't right. Because it can't find which view to go to.

**EX:** you must
`path('blog/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
path('blog/data', views.DataItem),`

Comment: Ok I corrected my error for blog/ and I did what you told me to do but it's not working or I need more details. excuse me for not understand fast

Comment: In CBV, the default name for the template is data_list. Try changing MYDATA in the template to data_list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a DataItem view and that's the issue. I think you meant to do like so:

`path('blog', views.my_financial_data),`

Comment: Hello, I replaced it instead of views.DataItem and it's not working ... when i load my page the data still not there

Comment: So, can you explain why you have 2 "blog" urls? I read the comment but it doesn't make sense. It's a bit confusing. Try to remove your first "blog/" url. I think Django it's going there before going to the other one

Comment: yes it's because I want my data to be load at blog/
I removed the first blog/ (template as ...) and I have an error 
"Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: If you want your data to be load at 'blog/', you should have: `path('blog/', views.my_financial_data),` and remove the other 'blog' one

Comment: Yes I did it already but it's still the same error if I remove the first blog/

Comment: If you print whatever in your template at the beginning of it, like `<h1>Foobar</h1>` can you see that when accessing that url?

Answer (score 0):

by setting urls.py and views.py like this

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
...
path('blog/', my_financial_data),
...

]

# views.py

def my_financial_data(request):
    mydata = DataItem.objects.all()
    print("My financial data : ",  mydata)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'mydata': mydata})
```

check for mydata in the console is there any value getting

Comment: There is nothing in my console or maybe i'm in the wrong place
MacBook-Pro-:mysite$ python3 manage.py runserver
['manage.py', 'runserver']
['manage.py', 'runserver']
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 26, 2019 - 12:40:42
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[26/Apr/2019 12:40:49] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4291
[26/Apr/2019 12:42:44] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4291

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it, thanks to you guys

It was the url blog/ like you told me and I had errors of {% url '' %} in my html so I had to clear all of these, thank you very much again, I will not make the same mistake!